# Export variables within callback functions || Re-edit

Tags: javascript

The truth ... I feel a little stand with this problem

```
foo(function(err, a){
    foo.buu(function(err, b){
    d = x(b);
    });
});
```

Considering that the structure can not be modified. How do I access the variable `d`?

Considering ... question really did not know that my problem is this.

```
var db = new Db(database, server);
db.open(function(err, db){
    list = new Array();
    db.collectionNames(function(err, collections){
        collections.map(function (coll){
            list.push( coll.name ) );
    });
});
```

but when making a `console.log(list);` returns only `[]` . I have no idea why?

Comment: It's global, you just refer to it.

Comment: Overall though, I return a Null or Undefined

Comment: Where are you putting `console.log(list)`? It's hard to answer definitively because we don't know how your `Db` class works, but if it's a proxy for WebSQL or IndexedDB, and the log call is below the `db.open` call, you're experiencing a timing problem, because `db.open()` returns immediately and runs its callback function asynchronously.

Comment: OK! ready ... and understood my mistake. But I think it's best to delete the question why not have anything to do with tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `d` as you have it in your code, assuming that it's the whole code, will be attached to `window`.

So accessing it can be done by just `d`.

Comment: (or `window.d`; in any case "ick")

Comment: Overall though, I return a Null or Undefined

Comment: @AlejoNext that doesn't make any sense. did you post enough code in your question? maybe we have missed something.